# Android (setLockTaskPackages)

Tags: android

i am making a kiosk app and i am using Google's screen pinning. i have managed to make my app a device admin using the custom xml file and a receiver that extends the DeviceAdminReceiver and i am also checking using a boolean parameter which is true indicating that indeed the application is device owner. when i try to use

```
devAdminReceiver = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), DemoDeviceAdmin.class);
String[] paramDevice = new String[]{"com.example.valantis.myapplication"};
managerPolice.setLockTaskPackages(devAdminReceiver, paramDevice);
startLockTask();
```

i get the following **error**:

```
SecurityException: Admin ComponentInfo{..} does not own the device
```

what is the problem?

**images:**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/l06bzqep6m9pvrm/11851195_10207295501010412_1943962580_n.jpg?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/loyfdsj3hzuafh2/11853053_10207295534171241_892119485_o.jpg?dl=0

Comment: here is the code for asking for device admin    https://www.dropbox.com/s/q9xlpm76h81wlv9/11831291_10207296073024712_607228203_o.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Anyone? Please this is for my MSc thesis

Comment: Links expired, this is why people should insert images, useless question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the application's manifest I can see that you try create a Profile Owner Application, no a Device Owner Application. It is because Device Owner Application's receiver should contain the following intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.app.action.PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Not like in yours manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Your intent filter is appropriate for Profile Owner App, no a Device Owner App.
Please see [Android Device Owner Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DeviceOwner) source code.

Because [setLockTaskPackages](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setLockTaskPackages%28android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String[]%29) method is allowed only for Device Owner Application, no a Profile Owner Application, you get an exception.

How do you check against if your application is a Device Owner Application, you should use [isDeviceOwnerApp](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#isDeviceOwnerApp%28java.lang.String%29) method.